# Advanced table-layout to CSS

Tags: html, css

I have gotten the assignment to code a website from tables to CSS. While this is easy I have one question on how to recreate one of the site's biggest detail.

Site is: [www.optimizer.dk](http://www.optimizer.dk/).

How can I recreate the labels coming out of the left side, while still having the content in the middle?

**Rest of the site is no worries.**

Is the solution to:

```
     padding-left: 200000px;
     margin-left: -200000px;
```

To fake the expansion to the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would possibly do it like this:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/umbvv/)

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden
}
body {
    background: #eee
}
#container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #bbb;
}
li, li span {
    height: 25px;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    background: #777
}
li span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    top: 0;
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/50x30/f0f/fff)
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><span></span>Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        Hi!
    </div>
</div>
```

This answer was based on an older answer I wrote: ['Stretching' a div to the edge of a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119898/stretching-a-div-to-the-edge-of-a-browser/5120341#5120341)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally here you would want a fluid width. See: http://jsfiddle.net/cbNvn/1/

```
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="center">Center</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

```
div {
    float: left;  
}

#left {
    width: 25%;
    text-align: right;
}

#center {
    width: 50%;
}

#right {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Expanding the page would expand the left column and the background image can repeat. The linked images can lay over the background as they do currently. The text-align:right attribute will keep the linked images on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 divs with float:left to create the 3 columns

Answer (score 0):

i would put it all in a div and set position:absolute;. then put your buttons in there own divs so you can move them.

or

put it all in a div and set the margin to -5%(mite need to play with this into it works). then make the image the background and put you text buttons in there own div's so you can move then to where you want them.

Then use float:left; to line them up